# What happens to a creature that passes its save against the Fanfare spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, dnd-3e, saving-throw

The *Fanfare* spell (*Song and Silence*) describes its effect as follows:

> Fanfare creates a trumpet blast so loud that it can shake the foundations of buildings or stop an army in its tracks.
>   Every creature within the area must make a Fortitude save.
>   Success means the creature is stunned for 1d4 rounds and deafened for twice as many rounds; failure means the creature takes 4d6 points of damage in addition to suffering those effects.

However, its header includes the line:

> **Saving Throw:** Fortitude negates

From the [SRD's section on spell descriptions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm), this means:

> **Negates:**
>   The spell has no effect on a subject that makes a successful saving throw.

So, does a creature that passes its save against Fanfare ignore the spell, or is it stunned?

*(Tagging note:  This question is about 3.0 content, but I want to know how it works in 3.5, which allows 3.0 content by default as long as a newer version of it hasn't been published.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the effects of both successful and failed saving throws by *creatures* is *already* addressed specifically in the description of the 6th-level bard spell ***fanfare*** [evoc] (*Song and Silence* 90), the entry *Saving Throw: Fortitude negates* seems to apply to the *secondary* effect of the spell against objects, which says, "Any object made of glass, wood, stone, or metal within the cone takes 2d6 points of damage, ignoring hardness."

Thus a successful Fortitude [saving throw by an object](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#object-saving-throws) (whether it's attended or not) will prevent the object from being damaged by the *fanfare* spell's effect.

***Note:*** The spell fanfare *is unmentioned in the* Song and Silence *FAQ (the typical method of handling concerns prior to the* 3.5 *revision) and is listed as* Not Yet Revised *by the Rules Reference Web column ["Feats, Prestige Classes, and Spells."](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20050110x)*

Comment: Is there an official source for trusting specific callouts in the text of a spell description over what's in the header?  I agree that this ruling makes the most sense, but curious if there's an equivalent of the "text trumps table" rule or similar for cases like these.

Comment: @A_S00 I hope it doesn't hurt my answer's credibility to say *I don't know that there's a specific source for picking a spell's description over its header*, but *without* using the  ruling in the answer, the spell *fanfare* (which, I admit *should* be badass as a 6th-level bard spell) not only stuns the army but also, on a good roll (say, 10 on 2d6) and *with no possibility of preventing the effect*, destroys *all* of the army's light shields *and*, except for, like, their heavy maces, *all their weapons!* Such an effect is sufficient for this DM to grant the objects saving throws. `:-)`

Comment: The alternative I was considering wasn't "objects don't get a saving throw," but "header takes priority, everything gets a Fortitude Negates saving throw, and the text describing stunning on a successful save is wrong (because it's overruled by the header)."

Comment: @A_S00 …Yet with the answer's ruling the spell works without having to subject the spell to house rules (and I *never* use the term *house rules* pejoratively!). I mean, the *fanfare* spell isn't a hill *I'm* willing to die on (despite it being a pretty awesome hill), but if the spell's seeming contradictions *can* be resolved with the information the spell presents—especially when it's resolved with specific *versus* general, the game's *most common* metarule—why *not* resolve the contradiction with the information presented?

Comment: The text being specific to creatures as an instance of "specific trumps general" hadn't occurred to me.  I'm convinced!

Comment: @A_S00 and HeyICanChan, objects get saves as their holder if they're attended

Comment: @Chemus Sure, *if* the effect allows the object to make saving throw in the first place, which this answer recommends that this spell does. Was that in dispute or is there part of the spell I'm missing or something?

Comment: No particular issue, I was actually responding to the comments; trying to highlight the objects' save is viable without a ruling (the (object) marker means that objects can be *targeted* not that they get a save that they otherwise wouldn't).